# Android FIDO2 throwing errors

Tags: fido

I used fido（Fido.getFido2ApiClient）and it worked fine before, but I suddenly got an error（UNKNOWN_ERR(28)） and no error message on October 17，

```
{
   "createCredentialOptions":{
      "rp":{
         "name":"xxxxx",
         "id":"xxxxxx.com"
      },
      "user":{
         "name":"xxxxxx@gmail.com",
         "id":"xxxxxx",
         "displayName":"FIDO2"
      },
      "challenge":"5DRfuLrSudl_2pHakpirhbbQf3G17lZ9HhdmPSzIZ4QMjwI0FNzQwJDzQlfPWksSwMJ6elchTnKrj3Ynhg5LIQ",
      "pubKeyCredParams":[
         {
            "type":"public-key",
            "alg":-7
         }
      ],
      "timeout":180000,
      "excludeCredentials":[
         
      ],
      "authenticatorSelection":{
         "userVerification":"preferred",
         "residentKey":"discouraged"
      },
      "attestation":"direct",
      "extensions":{
         "credProps":true
      }
   }
}
```